# How to paste an image in the clipboard to SE sites with Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I have one problem in pasting photo in stack exchange SE site IDE, and that is:

> Stack exchange writing IDE don't let paste the photo by Ctrl+v, and I
> must save the photo in my Ubuntu then upload it, but it was possible
> before.

Also, as you can see below, This could because of my chrome setting which don't have the paste icon on **drag and drop** option of adding images:

[image: sa]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to paste it in the wrong place!

Do not click on the picture button, directly press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>v</kbd>  in the textbox for the question (`Right Click -> Paste` works too).

I have tested this in Firefox and Chromium in Ubuntu 20.04, and it should work in Chrome too.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried now the right click and paste icon in the text box, and it doesn't work for me in chrome, but it is working on the Firefox!

Comment: @sosa I tested `ctrl+v` in both Chromium and Firefox, and tested Right Click -> Paste only in Firefox.

Comment: If it's working on your chrome then it is because of my chrome, then do you suggest reinstalling it or ...!

Comment: @sosa I have not tested in Chrome, but it works in chromium. I don't know if reinstalling Chrome would help.